# How to sort by a counter when using sharded counters

Tags: google-app-engine, sharding

I have an application where the main entity is a `Story` and users can vote for each story.  Each vote increments a `vote_count` for the story.

I am concerned about write contention on the story so I plan to use a [sharded counter](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/sharding_counters.html) for each story to track the votes.

Now my question: how could I get a list of stories ordered by number of votes?  For example: show the 50 most highly votes stories.

My initial thought is to have a task run periodically that reads the counter values and updates a property on the actual story.  It would be OK that the results of the query by vote were slightly out of date.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you may be doing a bit of premature optimization. I would skip the sharded counters until it becomes obvious that you need them. If you are pretty sure you will, then by all means, start with them. As for running a periodic task and caching results in a property for each story, that may be another premature optimization.

I have no direct experience with google app engine so hopefully somebody that does will have some info to share.

Comment: Re premature optimization: I agree that it is probably overkill for a new app without demonstrated write contention, but consider this a learning question and assume the app will receive 10 writes/second to the counters.

Comment: It's an interesting question. I had never heard of sharded counters before so I look forward to more responses.

Comment: I added a link to the question if you want to check out how they work.

Answer (score 1):

Periodically adding up data might be a good strategy to counter the sharding dispersion of counters.

You could also try other strategies for counting without shards, as has been described elsewhere:

http://blog.notdot.net/2010/04/High-concurrency-counters-without-sharding

(there you keep your counter in memcache, and periodically flush the accumulated value to the datastore)

How critical is your app to slight counting errors?